# R function creation: Nested Looping "Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds"

Tags: list, function, for-loop, nested-loops

I am attempting to functionalize the CIBSE Day Linking Algorithm from this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245383326_New_algorithm_for_generating_hourly_temperature_values_using_daily_maximum_minimum_and_average_values_from_climate_models

This algorithm is listed in equation format here:
[image]

I am only interested in generating temperatures for days after the planted date and before the last harvest date. That is why I have the conditional statements that generate 999 values for the day before the planted date and the day after the last harvest date.

**dput(head(mydata) output:**
structure(list(weather_date = structure(c(18324, 18325, 18326,
18327, 18328, 18329), class = "Date"), `Temp Max` = c(17.9160003662109,
22.1219997406006, 25.9589996337891, 27.1350002288818, 26.2180004119873,
16.5909996032715), `Temp Min` = c(2.16199994087219, 3.24499988555908,
5.54199981689453, 7.40899991989136, 8.51900005340576, 6.23899984359741
), `Time Max` = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15), `Time Min` = c(5,
5, 5, 5, 5, 5), plant_date = structure(c(18325, 18325, 18325,
18325, 18325, 18325), class = "Date"), `Last Harvest Date for that FV` = structure(c(1595116800,
1595116800, 1595116800, 1595116800, 1595116800, 1595116800), class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

**data sample:**

```
weather_date =  as.POSIXct(c("2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-06", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-08"))
`Temp Max` = c(17.916, 22.122, 25.959, 27.135, 26.218, 16.591)
`Temp Min` = c(2.162, 3.245, 5.542, 7.409, 8.519, 6.239)
`Time Min` = c(5,5,5,5,5,5)
`Time Max` = c(15,15,15,15,15,15)
plant_date = as.POSIXct(c("2020-03-04", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-04"))
`Last Harvest Date for that FV` = as.POSIXct(c("2020-07-19 UTC", "2020-07-19 UTC", "2020-07-19 UTC", "2020-07-19 UTC", "2020-07-19 UTC", "2020-07-19 UTC"))

use_me <- as.data.frame(cbind(weather_date,`Temp Max`,`Temp Min`,
                              `Time Min`,`Time Max`,plant_date,`Last Harvest Date for that FV`))
```

Function Creation:

```
CIBSE_Link <- function(WD,PD,LD,TempMin,TempMax,TimeMin,TimeMax){
 TempTime = list()

 t = 0:23 
 
 for (i in 1:length(WD)){
 
 if(WD[i] < PD[i]){
   
   for(h in 1:24){

TempTime[[i]][h] = 999

 }
 
 }
   
 else if (WD[i] >= PD[i] & WD[i] < LD[i]){
   
for(j in 1:24){

TempTime[[i]][j] = ifelse(t[j] < TimeMin[i],
                         ((TempMin[i] + TempMax[i-1])/2) -
                           (
                             ((TempMin[i] - TempMax[i-1])/2) * cos((pi*(t[j]-TimeMax[i-1]))/(TimeMin[i] - TimeMax[i-1]))
                          ),
                         ifelse(t[j] >= TimeMin[i] & t[j] < TimeMax[i],
                                ((TempMax[i] + TempMin[i])/2) -
                                  (
                                    ((TempMax[i] - TempMin[i])/2) * cos( (pi*(t[j]-TimeMin[i]))/(TimeMax[i] - TimeMin[i]))
                          ),
                          ifelse(t[j]>= TimeMax[i],
                                 ((TempMin[i+1] + TempMax[i])/2) - 
                                   (
                             ((TempMin[i+1] - TempMax[i])/2) * cos((pi*(t[j]-TimeMax[i]))/(TimeMin[i+1] - TimeMax[i]))
                                   ),
                             999)))


 }
   
 }
   
   else{
  
for(k in 1:24){

TempTime[[i]][k] = 999

 }


     }
   
   
 }

 }
```

How I am calling the function:

```
 CIBSE_Link(WD=use_me$weather_date,
            PD=use_me$plant_date,
            LD=use_me$`Last Harvest Date for that FV`,
            TempMin = use_me$`Temp Min`,
            TempMax = use_me$`Temp Max`,
            TimeMin = use_me$`Time Min`,
            TimeMax = use_me$`Time Max`)
```

**error that I am receiving:** Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

I have read several nested loop threads where op's are experiencing the same error, but I cannot identify what my issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort out an answer to my question. It looks like the problem occurred in the nested loop when I was trying to create a vector of j objects inside the list objects that were being built with the i loop. A simple mistake with a simple answer. I am sure there is a more clever way of doing this, but this works. For more info checkout the following repository on my GitHub: https://github.com/harrisonmckenny/CIBSE-Sin-14-R-1-Algorithms

```
CIBSE_Link <- function(WD,PD,LD,TempMin,TempMax,TimeMin,TimeMax){

#Initializing list & vectors:
  
TempTime = list()
  
smallvec_pre = c()
  
season_vec = c()
  
smallvec_post = c()

t = 0:23 #Military Time (R is not zero-indexed)
 
#Conditional Statement Waterfall:


 for (i in 1:length(WD)){ #day before planting
 
 if(WD[i] < PD[i]){
   
   for(h in 1:length(t)){
     
smallvec_pre[h] = 999

   }
   
   TempTime[[i]] <- smallvec_pre
 
 }
   
 else if (WD[i] >= PD[i] & WD[i] <= LD[i]){ #while plants are in ground

#Looping through linking day algorithm   
      
for(j in 1:length(t)){

season_vec[j] = ifelse(t[j] < TimeMin[i],
                         ((TempMin[i] + TempMax[i-1])/2) -
                           (
                             ((TempMin[i] - TempMax[i-1])/2) * cos((pi*(t[j]-TimeMax[i-1]))/(TimeMin[i] - TimeMax[i-1]))
                          ),
                         ifelse(t[j] >= TimeMin[i] & t[j] < TimeMax[i],
                                ((TempMax[i] + TempMin[i])/2) -
                                  (
                                    ((TempMax[i] - TempMin[i])/2) * cos( (pi*(t[j]-TimeMin[i]))/(TimeMax[i] - TimeMin[i]))
                          ),
                          ifelse(t[j]>= TimeMax[i],
                                 ((TempMin[i+1] + TempMax[i])/2) - 
                                   (
                             ((TempMin[i+1] - TempMax[i])/2) * cos((pi*(t[j]-TimeMax[i]))/(TimeMin[i+1] - TimeMax[i]))
                                   ),
                             999)))
}
   
   TempTime[[i]] <- season_vec #building list of hourly observations for each day
   
 }
   
   else{ #day after harvest is finished
  
for(k in 1:length(t)){ 

smallvec_post[k] = 999

}
     
TempTime[[i]] <- smallvec_post

     }
   
 }

TempTime[[length(WD)]] <- NULL #Must Null the day after harvest first because nullifying drops the index, so if we drop the day before harvest first, we cant use length(WD) as an argument

TempTime[[1]] <- NULL



return(TempTime) #list of hourly observations less the day before planting and after completed harvest

}
```